# Adding VBA reference in VB6.0

Tags: vb6

I have a old VB 6.0 application written by someone else. When i compile the application, it throws error on every line of code where VBA reference is required so fro e.g. it throws an error in the following lines:

```
Left$, Chr, Trim$
```

As soon as I prefix it with VBA.Left$, the error goes away. I was looking at the list of project References and saw only one missing reference called "Microsoft DTS run time 1.0". Where can I get this reference from and how can I add this in VB application. Also, is there any way, I can add VBA reference to VB application. I am running this VB application on XP machine.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You do not need to add a reference to VBA if the application is indeed written in VB6 (as opposed to VBA, as many people often tag them interchangeably). Both VB6 and VBA error on random string functions like `Left` when something completely different is missing in references. It will go away as soon as you fix the actual missing reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you should install Microsoft DTS runtime:

How to: Install Support for Data Transformation Services Packages:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143755(v=sql.105).aspx

After, add the VBA reference (if is missing)

Answer (score -1):

If you look at your list of Available References, you should see one for `Visual Basic For Applications`.  Make sure this is checked and you will be good to go.

If there is more than one reference for VBA, select the one for `msvbvm60.dll`.

Comment: `msvbvm60.dll` is the VB6 runtime. `Visual Basic For Applications` is the VBA type library. They are different things. In any case both VB6 and VBA like to error on random string functions (like `Left`) when any reference is missing. It does not have to be the reference to the library that contains these string functions.

Comment: But yet if I create a new project, highlight `Visual Basic For Applications` in the References window the file location is `msvbvm60.dll`.  Also, I have not experienced missing references causing errors on string functions, so that would be something I'll tuck away for the future.  Of course, a missing reference to VBA is itself very strange!

Comment: For some reason it does, which is a confusing name for `msvbvm60.dll`, but you cannot uncheck that reference.